# Bash - Error recovery by steps

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a solution to restart a bash script at a defined step when it previously failed.

For example, I have a bash script :

```
#my_script.sh:

  #Step 1 
  Action 1

  #Step 2 
  Action 2

  #Step 3 
  Action 3

  #Step 4 
  Action 4
```

After it fails at the `step 3`, I would like to be able to call it this way:

`./my_script.sh step3`

So it will start at the `step 3` and don't redo the `first 2` steps.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Make your life and the life of your co-workers easier and consider to use a *real* programming language.

Comment: @hek2mgl There's not enough detail to know if shell is the wrong language to use. If the actions just run other problems, shell is certainly a good choice.

Comment: @chepner Actually you are right, I was thinking that myself - after posting it. ;) But then I missed to delete it. Still I would say that the shell, regardless how much we love to play with it, is simply the wrong tool for application development. It's ok for really limited tasks. Limited in case of complexity. It almost always get's messy if the initial tasks changes over time. Probably the right comment below the wrong question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that if step 2 fails, you'd like to restart from there, and that step `N` is dependent on the previous steps `1 .. N-1`.

One way to solve this would be to create *stamp* files as you run your script.

Simply `touch step1-stamp` when you're done with step 1, `touch step2-stamp` when you're done with step 2, etc.

Each step would check if the stamp for that step exists before doing its task, e.g., for step `N`:

```
if [ ! -f "stepN-stamp" ]; then
  # do tasks for step N
  touch stepN-stamp
fi
```

A similar approach with a Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: step3-stamp

step1-stamp:
    @echo "Performing step 1"
    @touch step1-stamp

step2-stamp: step1-stamp
    @echo "Performing step 2"
    @touch step2-stamp

step3-stamp: step2-stamp
    @echo "Performing step 3"
    @touch step3-stamp

clean:
    rm -f step[123]-stamp
```

Note: This is all assuming that you don't want to run random steps. What you *could* do is to remove one or several stamp files and re-run the whole process from the start.  Especially the Makefile solution will handle this gracefully as it will force the re-running of dependent steps.

Comment: Very nice idea! I would suggest also to delete the stamp at step N-1 once the one at step N is created.

Comment: @mik1904 No. You would only delete the stamps when everything is done.  With the shell script solution, deleting stamp `N-1` when `N` is done, the `N-1` tasks would be re-run upon rerunning the script. With the Makefile solution, deleting stamp `N-1` when `N` is done, the `N-1` step _and all subsequent steps_ (i.e. every step that depends on step `N-1`) would be re-run upon rerunning `make`.

Comment: I see, because every time you run the script you check every stamp and if it exists you move on. So you don't give as input the step since it's all automatic. Sorry,now I understand. Very good one.

Comment: @mik1904 Ah, I see how you were thinking. I will clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` 4 introduced fall-through behavior in its `case` statement with the `;&` terminator.

```
# Contents of script
case ${1:-step1} in
  step1) echo "Running step 1" ;&
  step2) echo "Running step 2" ;&
  step3) echo "Running step 3" ;&
  step4) echo "Running step 4" ;&
  step5) echo "Running step 5" ;;
  *) echo "Unrecognized starting point: $1"; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Running this script:

```
$ bash script step3
Running step 3
Running step 4
Running step 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your code in a way that you give as input the step from which it should start like:  `./my_script.sh 3`. Then into your code you can use a case statement that takes as "input" `$1` which is your step given as input. I won't write the code for you but if you need further help, post your solution and I'm glad to give you some hints.